# Mapper and Reducer in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloud, elastic-map-reduce

I have a confusion about the implementation of Hadoop.

I notice that when I run my Hadoop MapReduce job with multiple mappers and reducers, I would get many part-xxxxx files. Meanwhile, it is true that a key only appears in one of them.

Thus, I am wondering how MapReduce works such that a key only goes to one output file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shuffle step in the MapReduce process is responsible for ensuring that **all** records with the same key end up in the same reduce task. See [this Yahoo tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#dataflow) for a description of the MapReduce data flow. The section called Partition & Shuffle states that

> Each map task may emit (key, value) pairs to any partition; all values for the same key are always reduced together regardless of which mapper is its origin.

Answer (score 2):

**Shuffle**

Input to the Reducer is the sorted output of the mappers. In this phase the framework fetches the relevant partition of the output of all the mappers, via HTTP.

**Sort**

The framework groups Reducer inputs by keys (since different mappers may have output the same key) in this stage.

The shuffle and sort phases occur simultaneously; while map-outputs are being fetched they are merged.

I got this from here

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html

Have a look on it i hope this will helpful